# Automation testing software for custom browser?

Tags: browser-automation, browsers

I'm looking for suggestions for software to use to automate regression testing of a browser I'm working on:

https://github.com/maidsafe/safe_browser

It's built on Electron but designed to work on our SAFE network protocol.

The two challenges I'm meeting so far are:
1) Automation S/W that will work with a custom browser.
2) Non HTTP(s) protocol.

I've looked at TestCafe which will launch the SAFE browser but it refused to work with non HTTP(s). I then looked at Nightmare Browser but I can't see how to get it to work with our browser (if it is possible I am happy to be corrected).

Any suggestions / pointers would be most welcome, thanks.

Comment: If it's an electron app you might be able to use cypress for it. I've never used it for that purpose (which is why I add it as a comment and not an answer) but it officially supports electron applications and, since it lives within the applications sandbox it should be (relatively) agnostic in regards to the used protocol.

Comment: It looks like it supports Electron as a browser but not Electron apps... https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310
 I tried to install it anyway to see if I could hack it but the installation failed, with an error referring to failure to install Chromedriver.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after much trial and error with TestCafe, Nightmare Browser, Nightwatch and Cypress, all of which I couldn't get past the above blockers, I've had a result with old school Selenium!!

https://applitools.com/blog/automating-electron-applications-using-selenium

I referred to the steps in this blog to get Selenium to work with a custom binary.